# How to catch response on get method android retrofit?

Tags: android, get, retrofit

I'm new to android development and trying to learn it. I recently ran into an issue, when I use get method I get a response as below:

[image]

As there is a **status** given as '0' from the backend I'm unable to catch the "**response_data**" array.
Could anyone please guide me how can I catch the response.
Thanks.

**API CLIENT:**

```
 public class ApiClient {
    private final static String BASE_URL = "http://api.xxxxxx.com/app/";
    public static ApiClient apiClient;
    private Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static ApiClient getInstance() {
        if (apiClient == null) {
            apiClient = new ApiClient();
        }
        return apiClient;
    }
 public Retrofit getClient() {
        return getClient(null);
    }



    private Retrofit getClient(final Context context) {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new 
HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        client.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
        client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws 
IOException {
                Request request = chain.request();

                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();


        return retrofit;
    }

    }
```

**MAIN ACTIVITY:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tvResponse;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvResponse=findViewById(R.id.tvResponse);

    ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getInstance().getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
    Call<ResponseData> responseDataCall=apiInterface.getData();
    responseDataCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseData> call, Response<ResponseData> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body()!=null && response!=null){
                List<ResponseDataItem> data=response.body().getResponseData();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseData> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

}

**RESPONSE DATA:**

```
public class ResponseData {
@SerializedName("response_data")
private List<ResponseDataItem> responseData;

@SerializedName("status")
private int status;

public void setResponseData(List<ResponseDataItem> responseData){
    this.responseData = responseData;
}

public List<ResponseDataItem> getResponseData(){
    return responseData;
}

public void setStatus(int status){
    this.status = status;
}

public int getStatus(){
    return status;
}
```

}

Comment: Could you show me your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse JSON in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-do-i-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: Its a simple JSON parsing.

Comment: @HudiIlfeld Ok I'm giving my code.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to let Gson know how you want to parse your json.
You can add many specific `TypeAdapter`'s for each specific class case or you can create one `TypeAdapterFactory` that will be used to parse all your jsons. Remember to add it to your Retrofit builder.

This code example is a `TypeAdapterFactory` that will ignore `status` and parse only `response_data` to your object.

```
class ResponseDataTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getDelegateAdapter(this, type);
        TypeAdapter<JsonElement> elementTypeAdapter = gson.getAdapter(JsonElement.class);

        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, value);
            }

            public T read(JsonReader reader) throws IOException {

                JsonElement jsonElement = elementTypeAdapter.read(reader);

                if (jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
                    JsonObject jsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
                    if (jsonObject.has("response_data")) {
                       jsonElement = jsonObject.get("response_data");
                    }
                }

                return delegate.fromJsonTree(jsonElement);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And on your Retrofit builder

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(ResponseDataTypeAdapterFactory())
    .create();

new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .client(client.build())
    .addConverterFactory(new GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
    .build();
```

And at the Retrofit interface, you only need to call the class that corresponds with `response_data`mapping.

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("/product-data")
    Call<List<ResponseDataItem>> fetchData();
}
```

With this implementation, you can remove your `ResponseData` class and care only about the important model.

Comment: ok sir thanks for your reply. Sir please tell me what will be the code of loop to catch the json array.

Comment: I have edited the answer -> at the Retrofit interface, you only need to call the class that corresponds with response_data mapping.

Comment: I have coded this example only for this answer, if you had to change something to compile, please, edit it here.

Answer (score 0):

For Catching response you use [interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) like [HttpLoggingInterceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) ,[stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/),[chuck](https://github.com/jgilfelt/chuck)

**Creating the Retrofit instance**

// Add the interceptor to OkHttpClient

```
  OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
        .addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor()) \\ StethoInterceptor
        .addInterceptor(new ChuckInterceptor(context))  \\  ChuckInterceptor
        .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .build();

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.myservice.com/";
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
  .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
  .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
  .client(client)
  .build();
```

for stetho interceptor

```
 implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
 implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0'
```

for chuck

```
 debugImplementation 'com.readystatesoftware.chuck:library:1.1.0'
 releaseImplementation 'com.readystatesoftware.chuck:library-no-op:1.1.0'
```

Comment: I have done the above things but where is the JSON??

Answer (score 0):

Make an interface

```js
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET
    Call<JsonElement> getTimeDifference(@Url String url);
}
```

Crate an Retrofit client calss

```js
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static final String TAG = "RetrofitClient";

    public static Retrofit geBaseUrl() {
        Retrofit retrofit = null;
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        }else{
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE);
        }         OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        if (retrofit==null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("...your base url...")
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }


}
```

```js
            String endpoint = "...your end point...";

            ApiInterface ret = RetrofitClient.geBaseUrl(url).create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<JsonElement> call = ret.getTimeDifference(endpoint);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonElement>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("String", "onResponse:  response" + response.body().toString());

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                       
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<JsonElement> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("response", "onFailure: " + t + "      " + call);
                    
                }
            });
```